# Find my Mac / BootCamp

Tags: macbook-pro, find-my-mac

If I have Find my set up and Bootcamp installed as well, will my computer be trackable when on Windows?

What happens if a thief steals my device and remains in Windows all the time,  or deletes macOS and installs another OS all together?

Will I ever be able to track the laptop? (in the Recovery Boot, or so)

Thanks!

Comment: Not according to this 8 years old question - see [Does Find my Mac work if you boot into Windows on BootCamp?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/44867/does-find-my-mac-work-if-you-boot-into-windows-on-bootcamp).

Comment: You should try, open Windows and from another device go to https://www.icloud.com/find and try to locate your Mac